# Xcode SDL Crashes on Start

Tags: macos, xcode4, osx-lion, sdl

This is my first time trying to use SDL on Xcode4, but immediately, there's a problem. The project will compile, but when I try to run it, it immediately crashes. I get this error message:

```
Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/*/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test
  Reason: image not found
```

With the code:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int main(int argc,char** argv) 
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
};
```

I followed the tutorial at this page http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/01/using-sdl-with-xcode-4/. I would really like to start developing apps for the MacOSX. I'm using a Lion.

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem with your code, your call to include SDL.h. The code should look like the following:

```
#include "SDL.h"
```

As the author of the tutorial you linked to, I can tell you I have an article on my site that introduces SDL and OpenGL. The article includes an Xcode 4 project that can help you get started with SDL on Mac OS X.

[SDL and OpenGL](http://www.meandmark.com/sdlopenglpart1.html)

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't have SDL.framework installed in the correct place. I put it inside of the Xcode.app library folder, not the parent folder. I really just got my macbook pro about a few days ago, and I almost have never used a mac before.